# windows batch if statement and string comparison

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement

I'm preparing some batch file which contain following code:

```
set /p NodeType="echo which node type?"
if "%NodeType%" == "HSS"
    (set o2ml=%CURRENT_PATH%\basicData)
```

While executing this, I'm getting following error:

> The syntax of the command is incorrect.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
set /p NodeType="echo which node type?"
if "%NodeType%" == "HSS" (set o2ml=%CURRENT_PATH%\basicData)
```

Answer (score 1):

The opening parenthesis must be on the same physical line as its `if`

Answer (score 0):

You may also not use `()`:

```
if "%NodeType%" == "HSS" ^
    set o2ml=%CURRENT_PATH%\basicData
```